# GreenDao gets me data that I can't see in database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

I'm developing a Hotel-booking app and I use greenDao.

I create a Hotel entity. This is the entry in my MyGreenDaoGenerator:

```
//  Hotels
private Entity createHotels() {

    Entity hotels = createEntity("Hotel", "hotels");

    hotels.addStringProperty("hotel_id").notNull().primaryKey().unique();
    hotels.addStringProperty("name").notNull();
    hotels.addStringProperty("country").notNull();
    hotels.addStringProperty("city").notNull();
    hotels.addStringProperty("address").notNull();
    hotels.addStringProperty("lt");
    hotels.addStringProperty("lg");
    hotels.addStringProperty("location");
    hotels.addIntProperty("stars").notNull();
    hotels.addFloatProperty("vote").notNull();
    hotels.addBooleanProperty("viewed").notNull();
    hotels.addBooleanProperty("favorite").notNull();
    hotels.addLongProperty("timestamp");

    return hotels;
}
```

As you can see, there is no "pictures" node. But I know Hotels have pictures, so I create a Pictures entity and relate it to hotels

```
//  Pictures
private Entity createPictures() {

    Entity pictures = createEntity("HotelPicture", "hotel_pictures");

    pictures.addStringProperty("image_url").notNull().primaryKey();
    pictures.addStringProperty("image_type").notNull();
    pictures.addStringProperty("image_path");

    //  PK

    Entity hotels = getEntity("Hotel");
    ToMany hotelToPictures = hotels.addToMany(pictures, pictures.addStringProperty("hotel_id").notNull().getProperty());
    hotelToPictures.setName("pictures");

    return pictures;
}
```

Easy.

In the greenDAO-generated "Hotel.java" now I get a suitable property:

```
protected List<HotelPicture> pictures;
```

Now I run my app and get some hotels from a webservice. Hotels include a Pictures node with a picture.

```
 "pictures":[
      {
        "image_type":"medie",
        "image_url":"url_to_the_picture"
      }
    ],
```

Now,
in the self-generated Hotel.java and HotelDao.java I can't see any method about setting a picture. I just have these:

```
public List<HotelPicture> getPictures() {
    if (pictures == null) {
        if (daoSession == null) {
            throw new DaoException("Entity is detached from DAO context");
        }
        HotelPictureDao targetDao = daoSession.getHotelPictureDao();
        List<HotelPicture> picturesNew = targetDao._queryHotel_Pictures(hotel_id);
        synchronized (this) {
            if(pictures == null) {
                pictures = picturesNew;
            }
        }
    }
    return pictures;
}

public synchronized void resetPictures() {
    pictures = null;
}
```

What I expect is one of the followings:

- GreenDAO is clever enough to see that there's a picture node in my Hotel object and saves it in the database
- GreenDAO is not clever enough. Pictures don't get saved in DB, should do that manually

What happens is that when I switch to the show-me-the-data activity, I see the picture. And I do after this:

1. I get hotels from DB

   hotelsList = (ArrayList) daoSession.getHotelDao().queryRaw(", hotel_agreements A WHERE A.HOTEL_ID = T.HOTEL_ID AND A.AGREEMENT_ID bla bla bla... no mention of HotelPictures here");
2. Show the pictures

   hotel.getPictures()

This leads to the before mentioned method, where the condition "if (pictures == null)" is evaluated and pictures is not null at all! It contains my HotelPicture object!

This seems to confirm my first idea: greenDAO is clever, saw the picture node and saved it in DB.

Too bad is that, if I do inspect the database, I see the hotels but don't see any pictures record

[image: Inspecting my SQLite DB, Hotels is full while HotelPictures is empty]

So, HOW does GreenDAO access this data, if they're not saved in the database? I'm getting crazy because it seems to me I'm losing the whole point of having a DAO, which means to me *Objects and Relations mapped to Java objects*, not *Java objects mapped some-to-database-and-some-wherever*.

Could anybody please help me to understand where I'm failing?

Thank you

Comment: It would help if you attach the code where you store the web-service info into your DB

Comment: Hello Jofre. Very simply:   ArrayList<Hotel> listOfHotels = MainSearchFragment.kalimaResponse.getData().getAvailability(); //This gets me the list of Hotel ovjects
  HCUtilsApp.Database.getDaoSession().getHotelDao().insertOrReplaceInTx(listOfHotels); //The HCUtilsApp is only used to retrieve the right DaoSession, but the insertOrReplaceInTx is the one of GreenDAO.

Comment: Are you storing the picture objects? With this code, you're only storing the hotel objects, loosing the picture references.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I wonder: why do I retrieve pictures with that daoSession.getHotelDao().queryRaw(", hotel_agreements A WHERE A.HOTEL_ID = T.HOTEL_ID AND A.AGREEMENT_ID bla bla bla... no mention of HotelPictures here"); in another activity? Because I do, pictures are retrieved inside the hotel objects with said query! I know that now I don't store pictures but I see that I retrieve them. So I ask myself: before I store them explicitly I should maybe learn how to store them unexplicitly, which is maybe what I'm doing now. But where are they stored?

Comment: Is this happening in the same activity in which you are getting the web-service info and creating de picture objects? I don't know, but maybe you could retrieve a picture object while it's in memory, although it's not in the DB.

Comment: It's actually in another activity. I guess there must be something dirti somewhere in the DAO, since it's the only reason I could imagine which would lead to getting the pictures back even though they're not in the DB.

Comment: Maybe somthing related with the greenDao cache. Try storing the pictures explicitly and you shouldn't have more troubles.